Is my understanding of the solution to this problem on conditional probability correct?
In the card game bridge, the 52 cards are dealt equally to 4 players—called East, West, North, and South. If North and South have a total of 8 spades among them, what is the probability that East has 3 of the remaining 5 spades?
Solution:
To find the desired probability, we use a reduced sample space. Given that North–South have a total of 8 spades among their 26 cards, there are 26 cards remaining, exactly 5 of which are spades, to be distributed among the East–West hands.
Since each distribution is equally likely, the conditional probability that East will have exactly 3 spades among their 13 cards is calculated as follows:

Total ways to choose 13 cards for East from the 26 remaining cards:
$
   \binom{26}{13}$

Ways to choose 3 spades for East out of the 5 remaining spades:
$
   \binom{5}{3}
   $

Ways to choose 10 non-spades for East out of the 21 remaining non-spades:
$
   \binom{21}{10}
   $


The probability that East has exactly 3 spades is then given by the ratio of favorable outcomes to the total outcomes:
$
P(\text{East has 3 spades}) = \frac{\binom{5}{3} \cdot \binom{21}{10}}{\binom{26}{13}}\approx 0.339.$
Thus, the probability that East has exactly 3 of the remaining 5 spades is approximately 0.339.

My understanding of conditional probability goes as follows:

Let an experiment have a sample space $S$ and $A,B$ be two events in $S.$ We define the conditional probability of $A$ wrt $B$ to be the probability of the occurrence of the event $A$ when the event $B$ has already occurred. We can also think this conditional probability of $A$ wrt $B$ to be the probability of occurrence of $A$ when the sample space considered is $B.$ Furthermore we define this probability as $P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B).$

However, I have some questions about the solution, or more precisely the approach by which they get yhe result. It seems to me that they are trying to evaluate the probability by considering the reduced sample space of the event North and South have a total of 8 spades among them.
It appears that they are considering  the number of outcomes that are containing in this event to be $\binom{26}{13}.$ But this is the part I don't get.
There are more than one ways in which the $8$ spades can be distributed among North and South. Say, the number of ways of doing so, is $n.$ Also, for each such way of doing so, there are $\binom{26}{13}$ ways of distributing the remaining $26$ cards between East and West such that each player gets $13$ cards. So, the total number of points in the  sample space of the event (,i.e. North and South have a total of 8 spades among them ) is $\binom{26}{13}\times n.$ But this is in contradiction to the number of points in the sample space of the event (,i.e. North and South have a total of 8 spades among them ) which is, $\binom{26}{13}.$
Now, let us denote the event that North and South have a total of 8 spades among them by $A$ and the event that East has 3 spades by $B.$ With this much anticipated correction, the number of outcomes in $A\cap B$  should be $n\times \binom{5}{3}\binom{21}{10}.$
So, the required conditional probability again comes out to be $\frac{\binom{5}{3} \cdot \binom{21}{10}}{\binom{26}{13}}$ as the $n$ gets cancelled.
But the way in which I propose to arrive at the same result (as described above) seems to be more meaningful. Is my approach correct? Specifically I want to know if my understanding of the solution is valid or not? I am asking this, because the solution given, seems to be not providing adequate explanations or reasonings so some questions about their approach remains.

Do you mean exactly $3$ or at least $3$? The answer to the latter question is just $\frac 12$

@lulu Yes, I mean exactly $3$.

I suggest editing your post to clarify that.  In any case, $\binom {21}{10}\times \binom 53 \big / \binom {26}{13}=0.339130435$ is the correct probability

@lulu Indeed that's the correct probability. But I am clarifying the possible reasoning to arrive at the answer.

The deck is split into two piles, the $26$ $N/S$ cards which contain $8$ spades and the $26$ $E/W$ cards which contain $5$ spades.  How you split the $N/S$ pile has no impact on how you split the $E/W$ pile.

@lulu Yes, that's the reason why I multiplied with $n.$

Not following.  Again, how the $N/S$ pile is distributed is irrelevant (and your $n$ methods for splitting the spades are not equally probable).  The $N/S$ players know exactly which cards $E/W$ possess (jointly).  We don't care about the specific cards, just the fact that they have $5$ spades between them.

Both way of solving the problem work fine in my opinion. The difference is your sample space.
Your way:
Sample space = {partitions of the 52 cards into N, W, E and S with each 13 cards}
which could for example be modeled as $$\Sigma = \{\sigma, \sigma: \{1,2, .. ,52\} \rightarrow \{N, W, E, S\}, \sigma \text{ takes 13 times each value} \}$$
The interesting events are:
$A$: "North and South have 8 spades together"
$B$: "East has 3 spades"
We are interested in computing $\mathbb{P}(B | A)$.
$P(B | A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{|A \cap B|}{|A|}$
$\mid A \cap B \mid = \binom{13}{8} \binom{39}{18} \binom{26}{13} \binom{5}{3} \binom{21}{10}$

choice of $NS$ spades
choice of $NS$ other cards
choice of $N$ cards among $NS$ cards
choice of $E$ spades among $EW$ spades
choice of other $E$ cards among $EW$ other cards

$|A| = \binom{13}{8} \binom{39}{18} \binom{26}{13} \binom{26}{13}$

choice of $NS$ spades
choice of $NS$ other cards
choice of $N$ cards among $NS$ cards
choice of $E$ spades among $EW$ cards

Hence $P(A | B) =  \frac{\binom{5}{3} \binom{21}{10}}{\binom{26}{13}}$
The solution:
The reasonning in the solution is the following: whatever the specific values of the 8 spades and 18 other suits cards that have been chosen in the North-South deck and whatever the way they are dealt between N and S, the probability of $E$ having 3 spades will be the same. So we can just consider that the cards given to NS have a specific fixed value. And work only with the remaining cards that have to be dealt between E and W. Since the specific name of the remaining cards is not useful we can suppose that the remaining cards are called $a, b, c, d, e$ for the 5 spades and $1, ..., 21$ for the cards of the other suits. Now the sample space is more simple because it is only the set of partitions of $\{1, 2, .. ,21\} \cup \{a, b, c, d, e\}$ into two sets of size $13$.
For example we can use as sample space the set of subsets of $\{1, 2, .. ,21\} \cup \{a, b, c, d, e\}$ that have 13 elements $$\Sigma = \mathcal{P}_{13}(\{1, 2, .. ,21\} \cup \{a, b, c, d, e\})$$ since the cards of W will also be known once we have chosen the cards of E.
In this new setting,

A = $\Sigma$ because we now suppose in the whole sample space that $NW$ has exactly 8 spades.
$B$ = "East has 3 spades" = "The partition has 3 elements from $\{a, b, c, d, e\}$"

And we now want to compute $\mathbb{P}(B) = \frac{|B|}{|\Sigma|}$
with
$|\Sigma| = \binom{26}{13}$

choice of the 13 cards of E among the 26 available

$|B| = \binom{5}{3} \binom{21}{10}$

choice of the 3 spades of $E$ among the 5 spades
choice of the 10 other cards of $E$ among the 21 non-spades cards

and we end up with the same result.
